# How to loop a component when I click a h3 tag in react using Hooks

Tags: reactjs

According to my question I have one Parent component, it s name is App.js and Child component name is Cardone.js. In Cardone.js component one Card is there. I am passing this Card component as a Child to Parent componet. Now in Parent component I have h3 tag Add One More. What I am trying to achieve is I need to loop a component maximum five times. it should start looping only when I Click h3 tag

This is App.js

```
import React, { useState } from "react";
import 'antd/dist/antd.css';
import Card from "./Cardone/Cardone"
import { Row, Col } from "antd";
import "./App.css"

const App = () => {
  const [comp, loopComp] = useState(<Card></Card>)

  const loopComponent = () => {
    loopComp(comp + 1)
  }
  return (
    <div>
      <Card></Card>
      <div style={{display: "flex", justifyContent: "center", marginTop: "10px", cursor: "pointer"}}>
        <Row>
          <Col span={24}>
            <h3 onClick={loopComponent}>Add One More</h3>
          </Col>
        </Row>
      </div>
    </div>
  )
}

export default App
```

This is Cardone.js

```
import React from "react";
import 'antd/dist/antd.css';
import { Card, Form, Input, Button } from 'antd';
import "./Cardone.css";

const Cardone = () => {
  // const { Option } = Select;
  return (
    <div className="site-card-border-less-wrapper">
      <div style={{display: "flex", justifyContent: "center", marginTop: "10px"}}>
        <Card style={{ width: 900 }}>
          <h3>Card One</h3>
          <Form layout="inline">
            <Form.Item style={{marginTop: "5px"}}
              name="firstname"
              className="firstname"
              rules={[
                {
                  required: true,
                  message: 'Please enter firstname',
                },
              ]}
            >
              <Input name="firstname" type="text" placeholder="Enter Firstname" className="firstname" style={{ width: 300 }} />
            </Form.Item>
          </Form>
          <Form layout="inline">
            <Form.Item style={{marginTop: "5px"}}
              name="lastname"
              className="lastname"
              rules={[
                {
                  required: true,
                  message: 'Please enter lasttname',
                },
              ]}
            >
              <Input name="lasttname" type="text" placeholder="Enter Lastname" className="lastname" style={{ width: 300 }} />
            </Form.Item>
          </Form>

          <Form layout="inline">
            <Form.Item style={{marginTop: "5px"}}
              name="email"
              className="email"
              rules={[
                {
                  required: true,
                  message: 'Please enter email',
                },
              ]}
            >
              <Input name="email" type="email" placeholder="Enter Email" className="email" style={{ width: 300 }} />
            </Form.Item>
          </Form>

          <Form layout="inline">
            <Form.Item style={{marginTop: "5px"}}
              name="password"
              className="password"
              rules={[
                {
                  required: true,
                  message: 'Please enter password',
                },
              ]}
            >
              <Input name="password" type="password" placeholder="Enter Password" className="password" style={{ width: 300 }} />
            </Form.Item>
          </Form>
          <Button style={{marginTop: "10px"}} type="primary">Submit</Button>
        </Card>,
      </div>
    </div>
  )
}

export default Cardone
```

Comment: The normal way to do this would not be to store components in state, rather to store the data for each component, and iterate over that array of data, rendering a card for each element.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you should change App.js like this:

```
import React, { useState } from "react";
import 'antd/dist/antd.css';
import Card from "./Cardone/Cardone"
import { Row, Col } from "antd";
import "./App.css"

const App = () => {
  const [comp, loopComp] = useState([<Card />])

  /*** change here***/
  const loopComponent = () => {
  if(comp.length<5){
    comp.push(<Card />);
    const newComp = [...comp];
    loopComp(newComp);
     }
  };
/******/

  return (
    <div>
       /*** and change here too***/
       {comp.map((m) => m)}
       /******/

      <div style={{display: "flex", justifyContent: "center", marginTop: "10px", cursor: "pointer"}}>
        <Row>
          <Col span={24}>
            <h3 onClick={loopComponent}>Add One More</h3>
          </Col>
        </Row>
      </div>
    </div>
  )
}

export default App
```

Comment: Hi @Ahmad Rahmani I am very Thankful for your answer, and a small request when I click Add One More it should stop Incrementing forms When I have 5 forms in the screen. so I request you please update your answer.